# como hacer visible la secuencia

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo

Estoy haciendo unas modificaciones en el formulario de odoo para crear productos ya que quieren que en el campo de referencia interna sea de solo lectura pero que aparezca con un consecutivo pero el campo lo esta mandado vacío a pesar de que tengo configurada la secuencia de product.product que puedo hacer para corregir este error adjunto codigo

```
    default_code = fields.Char(
    'Internal Reference', compute='_compute_default_code', store=True, readonly=True)

@api.depends('name')
def _compute_default_code(self):
    for product in self:
        if not product.default_code:
            sequence = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('product.product')
            if sequence:
                product.default_code = sequence
```

ese el la parte del codigo donde estoy haciendo la funcion del codigo que añadi para generar la secuncia ahora comparto como hice la secuencia desde la interfaz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como configure la secuencia no se si de aqui venga el error o porque motivo lo este mandando vacio

adjunto imagen del campo que se le hicieron las modificaciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el campo que estoy queriendo mostrar el consecutivo pero no lo esta mostrando, solo muestra que esta en  modo lectura